# Polymer on phonegap runs slowly

Tags: cordova, polymer

I am trying to create an app using the polymer design and phone-gap.
I have already designed all the pages in HTML, so I downloaded the Phone-gap desktop version.
And I downloaded the phone-gap app to my device. I managed to run the site locale,
But the site runs very slowly. Every time I touch the screen it take 4 seconds to absorb. What can I do to fix that? any ideas?
maybe use other framework?

By the why I don't know if that matters but the device I am running the site is LG G3.

Comment: I am aware of certain transitions that lag a lot, such as the `cross-fade-all`-transition. There's also some things like nesting transitions that could cause performance issues. Of course from what you explain it is rather hard to know if the hardware is insufficient or if there are some coding-mistakes.

Comment: Older Android versions perform sketchy when it comes to Apache Cordova  / Phonegap.  You might consider using Crosswalk in your project, which bundles a better runtime in your project: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/use-crosswalk-ionic-framework-android-apps/

Comment: Ok , Have you experienced with using polymer on crosswalk? do you think it would solve the lags?

Answer (score 4):

It might be because of the outdated webview. Apart from using `vulcanize`, I would recommend using intel's `crosswalk` webview. It will improve the performance drastically. It will update your `phonegap/cordova` application with updated `webview`.

[corsswalk-project](https://crosswalk-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using vulcanize https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize to embed all you html and polymer elements into one single HTML and javascript. I've also experienced better performance with chrome WebView.

Comment: You really that it would help that much? That it would solve the lags?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ahmadreza said Vulcanize them to import all the custom elements quicker.

But you need to know that Polymer 0.5.5 (Latest Stable) is not Production ready which by definition means it will be slow.

This is why the Polymer team is working on Polymer 0.8 which is written from the ground up to improve performance and compatibility with other frameworks.

Polymer 0.8 is still in alpha so if you use it right away the chances are that the APIs would change dramatically by the time 0.8 is stable.

Learn more about Polymer 0.8 at:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/